# Prevent angular material css styles from propagating to other components

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

so I have an override to angular material style in my global scss style like this:

```
.mat-form-field-infix{
   padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0 !important;
}
```

then I want to apply a different padding to the same element in my component since I need a  bit of more space to view more data; here is what I do in my component scss style:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix{
   padding: 0.2em 0 0.2em 0 !important;
}
```

but the last style gets propagated to all components once its load. so the question is how can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: use [css specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and remove your `!important` overrides.

Comment: how can this be done, can show in a example or something that points in the right direction @YuriyKravets

Comment: Did you change your view encapsulation?  :host with ::ng-deep should only affect child components.

Comment: yes I already tried that by doing something like ViewEcanpsulation.None

Comment: ViewEncapsulation.None makes the styles global; you would need to remove that for `:host ::ng-deep` to work as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `::ng-deep` is destined to be deprecated: see [Special selectors](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#special-selectors).

You can, however, follow a strategy like Yuriy describes:  If you want extra padding for all descendants of `my-roomy-component`, you can target CSS from your global styles like

```
my-roomy-component .mat-form-field-infix {
  padding: 0.2em 0 0.2em 0 !important;
}
```

And, again as Yuriy suggests, add more specificity to the selector to help the padding take effect without the `!important`.  Alternatively, the outer component can have its view encapsulation set to None so its styles become global, but scope with CSS selectors again.

Comment: How do you import your component file in global scss file? I am not able to import.